# easyAutocomplete function stops my keyup handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm writing a code to autocomplete the city search on my site. The problem is that the ajax function, once called, blocks subsequent calls to the keyup event. In practice, as soon as three characters are reached in the input, the ajax call takes the data from the API I am using (all fine in this point) but then something happens, and  the keyup event is not callable again (my console.log is not fired).

this is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="prova" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Enter name1..." data-behavior="autocomplete" />
```

this is my JS code:

```
$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;
        $('#prova').keyup(function (e) {
          var that = this,
          value = $(this).val();
          console.log("keyup");
      if (value.length >= minlength ) {
        searchRequest = $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + $("#prova").val() + "&format=json",
          //async: false,
          success: function(results) {

            console.log(results);
            var aList = results;
            var aOptions = [];

            for (i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
              //optKey = aList[i].geometry.coordinates[0] + ',' + aList[i].geometry.coordinates[1];
              optLabel = aList[i].display_name;
              aOptions.push(optLabel);
            }

            var options = {
              data: aOptions
            };
            console.log(options);
            $("#prova").easyAutocomplete(options);
          }
    });
  }
});
```

});

I debugged the code and I realized that the `easyAutocomplete` function is the one that blocks subsequent keyup calls. Something happens that I don't understand. `easyAutocomplete` is a Rails gem  but it is nothing more than a wrapper for the jQuery's easyAutocomplete plugin. Can you tell me what happens when I pass my `options` array to the `easyAutocomplete` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Try this. Change the lookup.js to be just the following:

```
let options = {
    minCharNumber: 3,
    url: function (phrase) {
        return "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + $("#prova").val() + "&format=json";
    },

    getValue: "display_name",
    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};

$("#prova").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Now should work the way you want. **Please** click on the **up arrows** to the answers if they helped you. That helps my ranking. Also, If it fixed it for you please click on the "This fixed my issue".
Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: It's perfect! But can you explain why my code was wrong?

Comment: It has AJAX built in. The loop was preventing it from working until three characters were typed. I followed the docs from Data providers - remote example at http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-remote and got the minCharNumber at https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete/issues/293.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the libraries. I got it working with your JavaScript:
I made a folder called lookup. In the folder I made two files:

1. test.html
2. lookup.js
3. Downloaded and unzipped the code for EasyAutocomplete-1.3.5 in the folder from http://easyautocomplete.com/files/EasyAutocomplete-1.3.5.zip

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lookup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="EasyAutocomplete-1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="prova" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Enter name1..." data-behavior="autocomplete" />
<script src="EasyAutocomplete-1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="lookup.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

lookup.js

```
$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;
    $('#prova').keyup(function (e) {
        var that = this,
            value = $(this).val();
        console.log("keyup");
        if (value.length >= minlength) {
            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + $("#prova").val() + "&format=json",
                //async: false,
                success: function (results) {

                    console.log(results);
                    var aList = results;
                    var aOptions = [];

                    for (i = 0; i < aList.length; i++) {
                        //optKey = aList[i].geometry.coordinates[0] + ',' + aList[i].geometry.coordinates[1];
                        optLabel = aList[i].display_name;
                        aOptions.push(optLabel);
                    }

                    var options = {
                        data: aOptions
                    };
                    console.log(options);
                    $("#prova").easyAutocomplete(options);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

That's it. Should work fine. Hope this helped you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I really don't Know... I mean, is a Gem problem? If you write another  character is still working?